# Reference for Choquet-like theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, locally-convex-spaces, choquet-theory

While reading a paper, I encountered the following statement:

> Let $K$ be a convex compact subset of a locally convex topological vector space. If $\mu \in P(K)$ is a Radon probability measure on $K$, then there is a unique point $x_\mu \in K$ such that $$\int_K fd \mu = f(x_\mu)$$ for every continuous, affine, real-valued function $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, the map $P(K) \to K: \mu \mapsto x_\mu$ is a surjective affine map.

I consulted "Lectures on Choquet's theorem" but I couldn't find this version in the book. Does anybody know an appropriate reference/proof?

**Edit**: With an affine function $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$, I mean a function with the property

$$f\left(\sum_i \lambda_i k_i\right)= \sum_i \lambda_i f(k_i)$$ when $0 \le \lambda_i \le 1$ and $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$, i.e. $f$ preserves convex combinations.

Answer (score 4):

The point $x_\mu$ is the barycentre of the measure $\mu$. Its existence and uniqueness is Proposition 1.1 in "Lectures on Choquet's theorem" by Phelps.

Comment: @R W But this proposition states something about $f \in E^*$ instead of affine functions!

Comment: What's the difference between affine and linear functions?

Comment: @R W An affine map preserves convex combinations. A linear map is much stronger.

Comment: Not so much - think about it

Comment: Ah an affine function is a translation of a linear function. But then there is still the issue of domain. Can any affine function on $K$ be extended to an affine function on the locally convex space?

Comment: I presume Hahn - Banach would help

Comment: @R W Does Hahn-Banach allow us to extend affine functions on the compact subset $K$?